# How do I specify that a function takes a HashMap?

Tags: rust

How do I specify a non-primitive type as a Rust function parameter - specifically, a `HashMap`? For example:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

// a main function that would call fibbonacci...

// Here the hashmap would be used for memoizing;
// maybe ugly, but it's a first attempt
fn fibbonacci(n: i32, cache: ??) -> i32 {
}
```

I've tried:

- `cache: Hashmap` => `wrong number of type arguments: expected at least 2, found 0`
- `cache: <HashMap>` => `error: expected ::, found )`
- `cache: std::collections::HashMap` => `wrong number of type arguments: expected at least 2, found 0`

[image: Dog wearing a tie with paws on a computer keyboard and tongue hanging out - "I have no idea what I'm doing"]

This is with Rust 1.0.0.beta.

Comment: For reference, this isn't an issue with non-primitives, this is an issue with any type that has *generic types*.

Comment: And for extreme pedanticness, the name is [Fibonacci](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci), with one "b". ^_^

Comment: @Shepmaster thanks - I'm sure the "generic types" bit will make sense to me when I get beyond "Xtreme N00b" level. :)

Comment: @Shepmaster Well, they did force me to misspell "standard" as "std". :)

Answer (score 9):

Let's check out the compiler error message for this code:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn fibbonacci(n: i32, cache: HashMap) -> i32 {}

fn main() {}
```

We get:

```
error[E0243]: wrong number of type arguments: expected at least 2, found 0
 --> src/main.rs:3:29
  |
3 | fn fibonacci(n: i32, cache: HashMap) -> i32 {}
  |                             ^^^^^^^ expected at least 2 type arguments
```

Note that it points directly to the issue and tells you that you need 2 *type arguments*. Rust requires that function arguments and return values be fully spelled out, there is no type inference at this point.

I don't know what you want the keys and values to be, so I'll assume `i32`:

```
fn fibonacci(n: i32, cache: HashMap<i32, i32>) -> i32 { 0 }
```

More verbosely, [`HashMap` has two *generic type parameters*](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html), referred to as `K` and `V` (but see note below). To reference a concrete type of `HashMap`, you need to specify what `K` and `V` are. You can also use more *generic* types but place *trait bounds* on the generics. This is a bit more advanced, and you don't need to worry about it to get started with Rust!

**note** - `HashMap` actually has 3 type parameters, but the third has a default value and isn't often used. That type parameter allows controlling the hashing algorithm used.

Comment: "it...tells you that you need 2 type arguments" - ah, I thought it meant I needed two for the definition of `fibbonacci`, not for the HashMap. Thanks!